# Unit Testing, overload output operator

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, operator-overloading, c++17

I want to make a unit test, basically i have a class Pawn and `<<` return the color of my pawn. The colors of my pawn are retained in a enum.

```
TEST_METHOD(outputOperator)
 {
   Pawn pawn(Pawn::Color::Blue);

   std::stringstream out;
   out << pawn.GetColor();
   Assert::IsTrue(Pawn::Color::Blue == out);
}
```

The problem is that my compiler said that no operator `==` matches these operands. What can I do ?
PS: This is my second unit test

Comment: Assert::IsTrue(Pawn::Color::Blue == pawn.GetColor()); should be how you define your test. You are trying to compare an output stream with a Pawn::Color which will obviously make the compiler go bonkers

Comment: `Assert::IsTrue(out.str() == "whatever text representation you expect the operator to produce");`

Comment: Please show the declaration of `Pawn::Color::Blue`.